# Assign name to excel sheet from variable in list

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

I have account names that are saved in a python list, let's say "account a", "account b", "account c" and so on. This list has been saved in a Pandas dataframe.

I'd like to have an excel file created for each of those accounts, but I want the file to have the name of the account that it represents.

My initial thought was to create a for loop and use xlsxwriter, something like this....

```
    with pd.ExcelWriter(workbook, engine = 'xlsxwriter') as writer: 
        account_list = ['account a', 'account b', 'account c']



for account in account_list: 

        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook([account_list])
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet([account_list])

        account_list.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = f'[worksheet]')
```

You can probably guess that I get an error, saying "expected string or bytes-like object."

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: From what I see with your code, you are trying to add individual worksheets named for the accounts in account_list to an excel file, not creating separate files.  Which would you like to do, sheets within a file or separate files?

Comment: I would like to do both. A file with the account name, with the sheet in that file also being the account name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable choosed in for loop:

```
import xlsxwriter

account_list = ['account a', 'account b', 'account c']

for account in account_list:

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook( account + '.xlsx')  # the file name is given by account
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(account) # if 'account' ommited, the sheet is named as 'sheet1'

    worksheet.write('A1', account)

    workbook.close()
```